# Align buttons in the td element to right

Tags: html, css-float

have the following html structure. I want to display the buttons in the td elements aligned to right. Tried float:right in the css. But no change. please let me know where i am making mistake. Thanks in advance

```
<div id="saveResetDiv" class ="saveReset" style="display: none;">
     <table id ="tableSaveReset">
     <tbody>
     <tr id ="buttonSaveReset" class= "buttonSaveReset">
     <td class= "save"  align= "right" ><button id="saveButton" class="save" bgcolor="#FF0000" >Save</button></td>
     <td class= "reset" align= "right"><button id="resetButton" bgcolor="#FF0000">Reset</button></td>
     </tbody>

     </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: maybe so? - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/5b65gv5b/ or https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/j9yooxb5/

Answer (score 19):

Use `float: right` property in CSS

Comment: Share your snippet in jsfiddle

Comment: Give !important property to your css class

Answer (score 1):

First give some width to the table.

Then you can use,

float: right (or) align: right

Answer (score -1):

You can only put the 2 of the buttons to align left or right

Comment: You can improve your answer by writing a code snippet.